# Storing directory as a variable for later use in linux script

Tags: linux, bash

In my script, I am holding the location (path) of a file as a variable.

For example, fileA

An example of its contents are

fileA=/usr/anotherfolder/somefold/"filenamehere"

However, when i call a command on the file in the script such as:

cat $fileA

or

cat "$fileA"

I get an error saying the file or directory doesn't exist. If I echo $fileA to see what the output is, and then run a cat manually from the terminal, it works fine, don't know what is going wrong. Any help?

Some debug info:

- fileA='/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"'
- echo '/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"'
  /home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"
- '[' '!' -r '/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"' ']'

For these particular lines

## Check for readable file

```
echo $fileA
if [ ! -r "$fileA" ]
then
    o=`expr $o + 1`
    echo "$fileA not readable."
    continue    
fi
```

Comment: try `cat "$fileA"` . Good luck.

Comment: have tried this, but it hasn't changed the result

Comment: Does `$fileA` contain special characters?

Comment: it could, but I have the proper escape character provided in such cases, an example of a failure case is: /home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"filecheck"

Comment: please post the result of command `echo $fileA`

Comment: + fileA='/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"'
+ echo '/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"'
/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"
+ '[' '!' -r '/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"' ']'

Comment: Output above shown from shell script run with debugging, those particular lines of code were thus: #Check for readable file
 echo $fileA
 if [ ! -r "$fileA" ]
 then
  o=`expr $o + 1`
  echo "$fileA not readable."
  continue 
 fi

Comment: Does the actual filename have quotes in it?

Answer (score 10):

If file name is `new`(not `"new"`), then change

```
fileA='/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/"new"'
```

to

```
fileA=/home/jacob/Desktop/CS35L/WORK/2/hw/test3/new
```

Comment: I don't believe I am adding those single quotes, any idea how they got there? They don't show up in the echo output? I thought that was just debug output syntax.

Comment: @jsjwooowooo I don't understand your debug info.

Comment: I just ran the script with a -xv command and that is what was outputed

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using "new" even if it is just new?

Comment: `new` and `"new"` are different inside `'...'`